# Find an interval between two intervals

Tags: python, dataframe, intervals

I have a pandas dataframe containing integer's start and stop values like the one below (sorted on the start values). Each row describes an event occuring in a video (there can be repeating row which describes two different events occuring between the same frames).

| index | frame_start | frame_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 7 | 39 |
| 1 | 39 | 57 |
| 2 | 39 | 57 |
| 3 | 58 | 400 |
| 4 | 417 | 615 |
| 5 | 485 | 500 |
| 6 | 640 | 745 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I would like to find the intervals where no events occurs like : [1,7], [57,58], [400,417], [615, 640] ,...

Do you have a solution for this ? Also, I would then like to find the overlapping intervals and with how many it overlaps (but that is another question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it easier to do this by converting the dataframe to a 2D list:

```
lst = [[1,1]] + df.to_numpy().tolist()
result = [(lst[i][1], lst[i+1][0]) for i in range(len(lst)-1) if lst[i][1] < lst[i+1][0]]

print(result)
#[(1, 7), (57, 58), (400, 417), (500, 640)]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is almost what I needed. For others who might stumble on this question: to retrieve the intervals I wanted I first needed to merge the overlapping intervals of my dataframe. Then I applied your solution and I've got the correct results.